# Add a button into scrollable ScrollView android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am very new to this. I have a simple requirement. I want to load a large image into, android scroll view. Also i want to add a button on top to image inside the scrollview, so that whenever scrollview scroll, my button should also remain scroll along with the back image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
        </ScrollView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kotlin code is :

```
package com.example.ocr_4
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView

import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val button = Button(this)
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.background_color)
        val imageUrl = "https://i.ibb.co/L5nxHqn/Ergo-Partlist-Page-2.jpg"
        //https://i.ibb.co/qgHKJVr/Ergo-Partlist-Page-1.jpg
        //https://i.ibb.co/dmJjC6f/template.png

        Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(imageView)

        // Set the position of the button over the image
        val layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 200 // X coordinate
        layoutParams.topMargin = 300  // Y coordinate
        button.layoutParams = layoutParams

        // Set the button's text and any other properties as needed
        button.text = "My Button"

        // Add the button to the ScrollView
        val scrollView: ScrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView)
//        scrollView.addView(button)


    }
}
```

This code i did with help to internet and chat-gpt. If I uncomment the last line `scrollView.addView(button)`, the app crashes. Please chelp, how can i add a button into scrollable scrollView.

Comment: What you are currently doing, is you are adding an image on the scrollview using xml layouts and the button programatically, by creating it using the code. Something simpler you can do is this:

          <ScrollView...> 
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <ImageView... />

Comment: @Kl3jvi, in my actual use case, button should be added by reading x,y co-ordinate from JSON. So I cant use xml layout buttons.

Answer (score 0):

change your horizontal scroll view code snippet like this.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+/container"
            >

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Button Text"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**Kotlin**

```
val layoutContainer : LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.container) layoutContainer.addView(button)
```

1. Add linear layout inside scroll view with id (container).
2. Inflate linear layout in kotlin and add button as view in container.

Comment: HI Sir, button getting added and scroll, but in my use case, I have to add button dynamically, by reading a json x,y co-ordinate.  How can I add this button from kotlin code? plz help.

Comment: @raju i have edit the above answer please check it out, Inform me if have still an issue.